# Parsing array from JSON response body with JSONAPI::Resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, jsonapi-resources

So I got two Rails 6 applications:

- Backend (API only)

  - with `gem 'jsonapi-resources', '~> 0.9'`
  - with `gem 'jsonb_accessor', '~> 1.0'`
- Frontend

  - with `gem 'json_api_client', '~> 1.18'`

In the Backend part I setup a Model (`Car`) which has a jsonb field to hold attributes (such as equipment). The relevant part of the Model looks like this:

```
# Backend
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  # additional_equipment is the name of the field in the DB which holds the JSONB
  jsonb_accessor :additional_equipment,
    satefy_features: [:string, array: true, default: []]
end
```

Then, in the frontend I setup the connection to this Model like so:

```
# Frontend
module Api
  class Car < JsonApiClient::Resource
    property :safety_features, type: :string, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

When I then do a create call via this connection, all values which are present in the request inside the array disappear. So doing this:

`Api::Car.create({safety_features: ['ABS']})`

will end up in a new Car record having

`Car.last.safety_features #=> []`

This only happens for the values inside arrays. All other values (strings, integers, etc.) get transferred correctly.

I got the feeling that I am simply missing a configuration somewhere. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think your issue may be related to the fact that "safety_features" is not the actual attribute name in the database. Can you try the following `Api::Car.create({additional_equipment: {safety_features: ['ABS']}})` or possibly `Api::Car.create({additional_equipment: {safety_features: ['ABS']}.to_json})`

Comment: @engineersmnky if `safety_features` just holds a string it get's safed fine. The issue is really just related to the value being an array unfortunately.